# Android Download Manager with progress dialog

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-download-manager

I have coded an android app using android download manager, and I try to show downloading progress using below code.

```
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                DownloadManager.Query q;
                q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                q.setFilterById(preferenceManager.getLong(strPref_Download_ID, 0));
                cursorTimer = downloadManager.query(q);
                cursorTimer.moveToFirst();
                int bytes_downloaded = cursorTimer.getInt(cursorTimer.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                bytes_total = cursorTimer.getInt(cursorTimer.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
                final int dl_progress = (int) ((double) bytes_downloaded * 100f / (double) bytes_total);
                mProgressDialog.setProgress((int) dl_progress);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
            }
        }
    }, 0, 10);
```

Everthing is working fine, but progress dialog is not showing smooth pregress that means I wish to show 1,2,3,4,5,6,.....100.

It's show initially 0, and suddenly change to 12% then 31% etc 100%.
My file Total size is 26246026 bytes, at the time of 0% my downloaded file size is 6668 bytes, 
at the time of 12% my downloaded file size is 3197660 bytes, and etc...

Answer (score 0):

From documentation,

> public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay, long period) 
>
> Schedule a task for repeated fixed-delay execution
> after a specific delay.
>
> Parameters 
> task  - the task to schedule. 
> delay - amount of time in milliseconds before first execution. 
> period - amount of time in milliseconds between subsequent executions.

Here, you have a period of 10 millis in your code. That might be the problem. Try 1 millis instead.

```
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
}, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't query too frequent it may hang your UI and use `ValueAnimator` for changing progress smoothly.

```
   myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                DownloadManager.Query q;
                q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                q.setFilterById(preferenceManager.getLong(strPref_Download_ID, 0));
                cursorTimer = downloadManager.query(q);
                cursorTimer.moveToFirst();
                int bytes_downloaded = cursorTimer.getInt(cursorTimer.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                bytes_total = cursorTimer.getInt(cursorTimer.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
                final int dl_progress = (int) ((double) bytes_downloaded * 100f / (double) bytes_total);
               changeProgressSmoothly((int) dl_progress);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
            }
        }
    }, 0, 5000);



private void changeProgressSmoothly(int progress) {
        ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(mProgressDialog.getProgress(), progress);

        int mDuration = 2000; //in millis
        va.setDuration(mDuration);
        va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                mProgressDialog.setProgress((int) animation.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });
        va.start();

    }
```

Comment: please you share your code on how your implemented it now